# How to dump mysql with all procedure and function using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export mysql dump file with checked option 'Add CREATE PROCEDURE / FUNCTION' in export page using Phpmyadmin but  neither function nor procedure is dumping ... please suggest me how i can dump with procedure and function

Comment: Could you provide more details what you have exactly tried?

Comment: Thanks for quick response ,,  Actually i am trying to take back up of zurmo crm's database from godady server ... When i am creating  sql file following above step both procedure and function are missing from sql file 
and i do not have ssh for terminal command 
In this case what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

In case you want to backup ONLY the stored procedures and triggers and not the mysql tables and data, it might be helpful like above... Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks .. But i can not use command line, because  it is case of godady server and i do not have ssh 
in this case what i should do